# Add empty fields to a word document via C# Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I'm trying to add several empty fields (i.e `ctrl+F9` shortcut) trough a loop to a word document (via VSTO) but for some reasons only the last one appears in the document.

Can anyone help me   ?

Here is the code I use :

```
        Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
        if (doc == null)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Paragraph para = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
            object fieldType = WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty;
            object text = "test" + i;
            object preserve = false;
            Field f = doc.Fields.Add(para.Range , ref fieldType, ref text, ref preserve);

        }
```

The output is :

```
{ test4 }
```

[MSDN Reference link here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.fields.add.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works just fine, but hard to see.  Problem is that all 5 fields are on top of each other.  Perhaps induced by stopping to soon and it is not clear how you want to proceed.  Arbitrarily, append this code to the for-loop body to make the fields more visible:

```
f.ShowCodes = true;
para.Range.InsertAfter("\r\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because every paragraph overrides the previous one.
The following example creates the new paragraph at the begging of the document

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ConsoleWord
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
               var  range = doc.Range(0, 0);

                object text = "test" + i;
                object fieldType = WdFieldType.wdFieldAuthor;

                Paragraph para = doc.Paragraphs.Add(range);
                doc.Fields.Add(range, ref fieldType, ref text);

            }
            doc.SaveAs2(@"C:\tmpc\aa.docx");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show all the text objects in the loop then try this instead....`

```
    object text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Paragraph para = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
        object fieldType = WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty;
        if(text.toString() != "")
        text = text + "test" + i;
        else
        text = "test" + i;
        object preserve = false;
    }
    Field f = doc.Fields.Add(para.Range , ref fieldType, ref text, ref preserve);
```

Output:
{ test1  test2  test3  test4 }

Or you can also try using Field.Update() strategically to wherever needed in order to update the fields being populated. Some times its the issue with buffering.

```
foreach (Field field in doc.Fields)
field.Update();
```

So you may try....

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Paragraph para = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
        object fieldType = WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty;
        object text = "test" + i;
        object preserve = false;
        Field f = doc.Fields.Add(para.Range , ref fieldType, ref text, ref preserve);
        foreach (Field field in doc.Fields)
          field.Update();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

concat `Environment.NewLine` to your text inside the loop