# How do I programmatically update Word fields?

Tags: c#, interop

I have a word document with fields: https://www.avantixlearning.ca/microsoft-word/word-tip-create-dynamic-word-documents-insert-fields/

There are number of fields that need to be updated, and updating them through the Word GUI is tedious.

I'm looking through the [Word.Interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.field?view=word-pia) and it doesn't look like Word.Fields supports changing the value of the field (or a way to identify fields beyond the index or checking the result)

Is there another approach I could try?

Comment: Are the word documents the new .docx format? If so you can use the OpenXML SDK. This question may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206121/how-can-i-update-all-fields-cross-reference-with-openxml-in-c I'd avoid the Word Interop as it has a dependency on office being installed.

Answer (score 1):

To access the `Fields` collection of the current document, you could use [ActiveDocument.Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.fields?view=vsto-2017) or [ActiveDocument.Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.variables). If you want to access a non-active document, you have to create or open a `Document` object which represents it.

Most `Word` `Field` objects need not and cannot be changed in terms of their values. Variables can be referenced within the document text as `DOCVARIABLE` fields.

See a related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8156643/1911064) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43428425/1911064).

The following shows how this works in practice:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace akWordFieldDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            //  start Word application
            var oWord = new Word.Application
            {
                Visible = true
            };

            //  create new document
            var oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add();

            //  add a DOCVARIABLE field
            Word.Paragraph para = oDoc.Paragraphs.Add();
            object fieldType = Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty;
            object text = "DOCVARIABLE myVar";
            object preserveFormatting = true;
            var field = oDoc.Fields.Add(para.Range, ref fieldType, ref text, ref preserveFormatting);

            //  set the value of the DOCVARIABLE
            oDoc.Variables["myVar"].Value = "some value";

            oDoc.Fields.Update();
            oDoc.SaveAs2("myDoc.docx");
            oDoc.Close();
            oWord.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems Document.Variables[name] is readonly.